# Hashmap in Freemarker Macro is not working

Tags: java, list, hashmap, macros, freemarker

I need to iterate through a hashmap in a freemarker macro. But for some reason it doesnt work and I cannot find my mistake.

This is the macro that I wrote to test the iteration:

```
<#macro listtest products>

    <#list products as name, price >
        ${name}: ${price} <br>
    </#list>

</#macro>
```

And this is the example that I wrote:

```
<@listtest products={ "apple": 5, "banana": 10, "kiwi": 15 } />
```

I get the following error message regarding the line with "<#list products as name, price >":

Encountered ",", but was expecting:
    ">"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the java code where you create your map. Also, what version of freemarker are you using?

Comment: we have tried at least 5 different freemarker hash iteration regimes and NONE of them work. Using FreeMarker Version: 2.3.26-incubating in Netsuite

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?keys` to iterate over JSON entries:

```
<#list products?keys as k>
  ${k} : ${products[k]} <br>
</#list>
```